# ROS - Convert Float64MultiArray to PointCloud2

Tags: ros

How do you convert a `Float64MultiArray` message into a `PointCloud2` message in ROS?

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic skeleton :

```
std_msgs::Float64MultiArray map_info;
tf::matrixEigenToMsg(map,map_info );

sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;
cloud.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
cloud.width  = map_info.end()+1;
cloud.height = 1;
cloud.is_bigendian = false;
cloud.is_dense = false;

sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Modifier modifier(cloud);
modifier.setPointCloud2FieldsByString(1,"xy");
modifier.resize(map_info.end()+1);

sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Iterator<float> out_x(cloud, "x");
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Iterator<float> out_y(cloud, "y");

for (double i=0;i<map_info.end();i++)
{
    *out_x = i;
    *out_y = map_info.data[i];
    ++out_x;
    ++out_y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please edit you answer by providing full code for conversion? In order for me to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Where is it visible the Float64MultiArray input message? I see you refer to map_info

Comment: I was referring to provide a full conversion code with for example Callback that takes the Float64MultiArray input message, then does the logic, then publishes the PointCloud2 output

Comment: Can I ask why you use this line? tf::matrixEigenToMsg(map,map_info ); The object map is not defined, and not used in the pipeline

Comment: most of the time people have a matrix from read data. if you have a buit array, no need of it.

Comment: Hi Nilanaka, the code you provided unfortunately is not compiling. In order for us to standardize the answer and for me to accept it could you please edit your question by having everything wrapped in a Callback that takes a Float64MultiArray message as INPUT? More specifically void Callback(const std_msgs::Float64MultiArray::ConstPtr& msg)